# Plotting bargraph with x axis categories in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How is it possible to plot the x axis categories in ascending order in Python.

I'm plotting the Total Sales grouping by the region. The regions are Philadelphia, Los Angeles and Chicago. I want the graph plotted with the bar pertaining to Chicago coming first and followed by other regions in ascending order.

Sharing the dataframe and code below

Dataframe
[TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcbjv.png)

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sales = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/varun/Downloads/TEST.csv')
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
ax = sns.countplot(x = 'Region', data = sales)
plt.title('Regionwise Sales')
for p in ax.patches:
        height = p.get_height()
        ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,height + 0.05,'{:1.2f}%'.format(100*height/float(len(sales))),ha="center")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Post your code if you want help. So far no one here even knows what library you use to plot if any or how you store your data.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for the [sns.countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) object has a parameter for the order of the the x axis,
you can enter whatever order you want in the form of an array of strings. [image]

```py
ax = sns.countplot(x = 'Region', data = sales, order=["CG","PH","LA"])
```

**The above image was only run with the first ~10 lines of data**
Hope this helps!

*EDIT:*
For the second part of the question, your best bet would be to sort the strings before hand and then use that list.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Let me add one more thing, what if the bars have to be arranged in the increasing (or decreasing) order of their values. Here, the one with the highest percentage sales should come first.